count(ref) is not showing when count is zero in group by - in oracle
SELECT ID, COUNT(REFERENCE) 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE ID IN ('6004_1', '1269_1') 
  AND REFERENCE IN ('ADD', 'DIV') 
GROUP BY ID, REFERENCE
HAVING COUNT(REFERENCE) >= 0

REFERENCE column has ADD FOR row 6004_1.
But REFERENCE column does not have any of its values for the id 1269_1.
Issue is only 6004_1 value is showing as 1.
1269_1 is not showing as 0

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; and the expected output for that sample data. At the moment it is unclear whether 1269_1 has any rows in the database and what the reference value is for that row.

When you use a GROUP BY clause, if there are zero rows within the input for that group then the group will not be shown. If you want to always include a group even when there is not then you need to use an OUTER JOIN to the set of all expected values so there would always be at least one row:
WITH groups (id, reference) AS (
  SELECT '6004_1', 'ADD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '6004_1', 'DIV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1269_1', 'ADD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1269_1', 'DIV' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT g.id,
       g.reference,
       COUNT(t1.reference) AS num_reference
FROM   groups g
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
       ON g.id = t1.id AND g.reference = t1.reference
GROUP BY
       g.id,
       g.reference;

or:
WITH ids (id) AS (
  SELECT '6004_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1269_1' FROM DUAL
),
references (reference) AS (
  SELECT 'ADD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DIV' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT i.id,
       r.reference,
       COUNT(t1.reference) AS num_reference
FROM   ids i
       CROSS JOIN references r
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
       ON i.id = t1.id AND r.reference = t1.reference
GROUP BY
       i.id,
       r.reference;

or:
SELECT i.id,
       r.reference,
       COUNT(t1.reference) AS num_reference
FROM   (
         SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS id
         FROM   TABLE(SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('6004_1', '1269_1'))
       ) i
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS reference
         FROM   TABLE(SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('ADD', 'DIV'))
       ) r
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
       ON i.id = t1.id AND r.reference = t1.reference
GROUP BY
       i.id,
       r.reference;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table1 (id, reference) AS
SELECT '6004_1', 'ADD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '6004_1', 'DIV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1269_1', 'ADD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '9999_1', 'ADD' FROM DUAL;

All output:



ID
REFERENCE
NUM_REFERENCE




6004_1
ADD
1


6004_1
DIV
1


1269_1
ADD
1


1269_1
DIV
0



fiddle
